# Django ORM slow on multiple joins

Tags: mysql, django-orm, entity-attribute-value

I'm using Django ORM , **eav-django**, mysql 5.1 on my server. 
When it gets to do query like this it's totally killing my small server (in fact my 4core dev machine as well). Is this because it's referring to itself ie bon_attr table ?

Are there any good tips on speeding things up a bit (except caching it)?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `bon_property`.`id`, `bon_property`.`company_id`, `bon_property`.`remote_id`, `bon_property`.`category_id`, `bon_property`.`slug`, `bon_property`.`address_id`, `bon_property`.`address_given_id`, `bon_property`.`agent_contact_id`, `bon_property`.`date_modyfied`, `bon_property`.`status` 

FROM `bon_property` 
INNER JOIN `bon_attr` ON (`bon_property`.`id` = `bon_attr`.`entity_id`) 
INNER JOIN `bon_attr` T5 ON (`bon_property`.`id` = T5.`entity_id`) 
INNER JOIN `bon_attr` T6 ON (T5.`id` = T6.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `bon_attr` T10 ON (`bon_property`.`id` = T10.`entity_id`) 
INNER JOIN `bon_attr` T11 ON (T10.`id` = T11.`id`) 

WHERE ((`bon_attr`.`value_float` <= 1  
AND `bon_attr`.`entity_type_id` = 18 ) 
AND (`bon_attr`.`schema_id` = 23  
AND `bon_attr`.`entity_type_id` = 18 ) 
AND (T6.`value_float` >= 1  
AND T6.`entity_type_id` = 18 ) 
AND (T6.`schema_id` = 23 
AND T6.`entity_type_id` = 18 ) 
AND `bon_property`.`company_id` = 27  
AND (T11.`value_float` >= 200000  
AND T11.`entity_type_id` = 18 ) 
AND (T11.`schema_id` = 42  
AND T11.`entity_type_id` = 18 ) 
AND `bon_property`.`status` = 1 ) 

ORDER BY `bon_property`.`id` ASC;
```

even this query is killing server:

```
SELECT  * FROM `bon_property` 

INNER JOIN `bon_attr` T3 ON (`bon_property`.`id` = T3.`entity_id`) 
INNER JOIN `bon_attr` T4 ON (T3.`id` = T4.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `bon_attr` T8 ON (`bon_property`.`id` = T8.`entity_id`) 
WHERE `bon_property`.`status` = 1
```

after about 4 min slow-query log says 
Query_time: 430.093778  Lock_time: 0.000247 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 164591659
and i have a huge nr of rows examined ...
my config : http://dpaste.com/hold/833263/

edit explain on similar query:

```
1   PRIMARY T4  ref PRIMARY,entity_type_id,bon_attr_299a9dd7,bon_attr_...   bon_attr_6f9d19 4   const   9770    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY T9  ref PRIMARY,entity_type_id,bon_attr_299a9dd7,bon_attr_...   bon_attr_6f9d19 4   const   12037   Using where
1   PRIMARY T3  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   om.T4.id    1   Using where
1   PRIMARY bon_property    eq_ref  PRIMARY,bon_property_543518c6   PRIMARY 4   om.T3.entity_id 1   Using where
1   PRIMARY T8  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   om.T9.id    1   Using where; Distinct
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U1  ref entity_type_id,bon_attr_299a9dd7,bon_attr_6f9d19    entity_type_id  12  const,func,const    1   Using where; Using index
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U0  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   func    1   Using where; Using index
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U1  ref entity_type_id,bon_attr_299a9dd7,bon_attr_147166d7  entity_type_id  8   const,func  17  Using where; Using index
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U0  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   func    1   Using where; Using index
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U1  ref entity_type_id,bon_attr_299a9dd7,bon_attr_6f9d19    entity_type_id  12  const,func,const    1   Using where; Using index
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U0  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   func    1   Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U1  ref entity_type_id,bon_attr_299a9dd7,bon_attr_147166d7  bon_attr_147166d7   5   const   1   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  U0  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   func    1   Using where; Using index
```

EDIT 2
Yes it was a question of indexing it even more EXPLAIN has been very helpful as well as Duke Silver.

Comment: Are you sure that all of your join columns are indexed? Also if you put the where conditions within the inner joins you may see an improvement.

Comment: yep, all of them have updated indexes ...

Comment: The generated query seems quite suboptimal, can you share what python code actually generates these?

Comment: Most of the time is a standard django filter()/exclude() which i've overriden so that in addition i can query the eav attributes (and chain those) Problem is when i try query several eav attributes or I should rather say perform multiple joins on attr table .... i can't figure out what slows it down so much..